# How to understand slot and task in Apache Flink

Tags: architecture, apache-flink, flink-streaming

I've read many docs about this issue but I'm still confused by the two concepts: slot and task.

Let's see the example of WordCount.

[image]

As my understanding, each yellow circle is an operator, and Flink can do some optimization, meaning that it can merge more than one operator into an operator chain. In this example, `Source` and `map()` can be merged so it becomes as below:

[image]

The whole stream becomes three tasks: `Source + map()`, `KeyBy()/window()/apply()` and `Sink`.

If I'm right,one slot is one thread in the TaskManager of Flink, so I'm confused now. In this example, we have three tasks, so does it mean that we must have three slots (each task has its own thread), or does it mean that we must create a TaskManager with three slots for this example? What if the TaskManager has only one or two slots? If we have less than three slots, some exception will be thrown?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One **Slot** is **not** one thread. One slot can have multiple threads.

A **Task** can have multiple parallel instances which are called **Sub-tasks**. Each **sub-task** is ran in a separate thread.

Multiple sub-tasks from different tasks can come together and share a slot. This group of sub-tasks is called a **slot-sharing group**. Please note that two sub-tasks of the same task (parallel instances of the same task) can not share a slot together.

The number of slots in a Task Manager represents the maximum parallelism it can support. For example, if your job has a parallelism of one for each operator. It can be ran in a Task Manager with one slot. The reason is that all the sub-tasks share the same slot and belong to a slot-sharing group.

Let's consider another example. Assume that you have a Task Manager with one slot and the word count job with a parallelism of one for all operators except `KeyBy()/window()/apply()` which has 3. When you submit this job, it will fail because you had only one slot. One sub-task of `KeyBy()/window()/apply()` will be sharing a slot with sub-tasks of `Source + Map` and `Sink`. But the other two sub-tasks won't find a slot (because two subtasks of the same task cannot share a slot as mentioned earlier)

Comment: One correction: a while back the Flink community decided to clarify the meaning of the term "task" so that "task" now has the same meaning in our docs and discussions that it has always had in the code -- "Tasks encapsulate exactly one parallel instance of an Operator or Operator Chain". So there is no longer any real technical distinction between tasks and subtasks, though the emphasis is a bit different. See https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/concepts/glossary.html#task and https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/concepts/glossary.html#sub-task.

Comment: God, naming is really an important thing :O

Comment: how many threads can a flink task manager have? is there a limit